# Windows phone 8: Live tile updates in the emulator but not when downloaded from the maket

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, live-tile, windows-phone-7.8

I have made an app with live tile for windows phone 8. The tile is programmed to refresh every 30 seconds. When the run the app in the emulator or when I deploy the app in my cell (Lumia 920) the tile works fine. But surprisingly when I downloaded the same app from the market and run it on the same device the tile doesn't update.

I did quite a bit of research on this problem and found that a similar problem is observed by many other people which can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/7b54b400-3aaf-47a8-ba48-a15447406f73/live-tile-not-updating-after-the-78-update-for-some-of-my-users).

Kindly tell me what is going wrong.

Extra Info : I have tried resizing the tile, pin and unpin the tile and hard reset. I have also tried changing the refresh period (initially the refresh period was 5 seconds). I have also checked that the background task is allowed for the app.

Thanks,
Apurva Pathak

Answer (score 1):

Background agents have certain limitations, as listed below.

```
Background tasks can minimally be run every 30 minutes. There is a debug-only API to run them more regularly, but this is not available for released apps.
Some low power devices do not support background agents
Background tasks are limited by number on each device and can be enabled or disabled from application settings.
They do not work when power saver mode is activated.
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. But when I deploy the app in the same device the tile works fine and refreshes every 30 seconds. Why does this problem occur only when I download and install that app from the market?
-Apurva Pathak

Comment: For testing purpose ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));  and  api behavior different in testing and in market.

Answer (score 0):

As Mahantesh correctly pointed out your tiles work when you deploy the application because the ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest() is allowed to run for a 60 seconds period for debugging and testing purposes **ONLY**.

Therefore this method cannot be called and it wont work with a time limit less than 30 minutes if the application is published to the market and users download it from there.